# If $f$ is continuous and $f(x_0) = \alpha > 0$, why is there some interval on which $f(x) > \frac{\alpha}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

[image]

I do not understand the second line of the proof. How do we know that $f(x)>\frac{\alpha}{2}$?

Comment: By continuity there exists some $\delta$ such that for all $x$ with $|x - x_0| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < f(x_0)/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - x_0| < \delta$. Setting $\varepsilon = \frac{\alpha}{2}$, we see that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - x_0| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \frac{\alpha}{2}$. Now note that

$$|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \frac{\alpha}{2} \Longleftrightarrow -\frac{\alpha}{2} < f(x) - f(x_0) < \frac{\alpha}{2} \Longleftrightarrow f(x_0) - \frac{\alpha}{2} < f(x) < f(x_0) + \frac{\alpha}{2}.$$

In particular, if $x \in (x_0 -\delta, x_0 + \delta)$, then $|x - x_0| < \delta$, so $f(x) > f(x_0) - \frac{\alpha}{2} > \alpha - \frac{\alpha}{2} = \frac{\alpha}{2}$.

---

Note, the same proof can be used to show that for any $\beta < \alpha$, we could find an interval $I$ centred at $x_0$ with $f(x) > \beta$ on $I$. In that case, choose $\epsilon = \alpha - \beta$.